# How to set empty file description using AutoItWrapper?

Tags: manifest, autoit, scite

When I add this wrapper directive it changes the description field of my executable. But when I leave it empty (or omit the directive) its value defaults to `Aut2Exe`.

```
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Res_Description=
```

How can I change this behavior? Is there a parameter for AutoIt3Wrapper.exe that leaves it empty? This is the compile command executed by SciTE:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\SciTE\AutoIt3Wrapper\AutoIt3Wrapper.exe" /in "C:\...\myscript.au3" /console
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the AutoIt3Wrapper source code, which is provided in the installation, the following line (line 2326 in my installation) reads:

```
If $INP_Description = "" Then $INP_Description = FileGetVersion($AutoItBin, "FileDescription")
```

I believe that to be the source of the Aut2Exe description.

How to force the description to be blank is a bit trickier. The quick and easy hack is to have a script that runs after compilation that removes the description, I usually have reshacker somewhere to hand for tasks like this.

Long term, I will put the issue to the developer, as it seems strange to set a description when the user has explicitly left it blank.